# reloading a form and not the whole page on submit ANGULAR 8

Tags: angular

I need to reload just my form, after I click the submit button and not the whole page...

i have put location.reload(); in my submit() function, but it reloads the whole page, is there a way to load only the form..
my form name is empForm

```
submit(){
   if (data["message"] === "Schedules Created Successfully") {
        this.toaster.start({
          type: "success",
          message: "Saved"
        });
       location.reload();
      } else {
        this.toaster.start({
          type: "fail",
          message: "could not save"
        });
      }

}
```

this reloads the page, even before the toaster of "saved" is shown

Comment: Can you add the template? is this a template driven form or reactive?

Comment: @JasonWhite yes it works

Comment: sorry i deleted ur comment by mistake

Comment: can you retype it

Comment: it is reactive form, formarry, formGroup

Comment: empForm.reset() worked , thanks

Comment: `empForm.reset()` will reset the controls completely.  If there are prefilled values for the form you can use `empForm.patch({ });` with key value of the fields you want to fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to emulate a browser postback or move in the route in order to reset the form. You only need to call the reset method in the same form and this will back to init state.

eg:

```js
public onSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
    return false;
  }

  const {values} = this.formGroup;
  // perform something with the data
  // eg send to backend
  
  this.formGroup.reset()
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (submit)="onSubmit($event)">
  <button type="submit">SEND</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: Any required field will be considered invalid after the `FormGroup.reset()`. Try calling `FormGroupDirective.resetForm()`. You can get `FormGroupDirective` using `@ViewChild(FormGroupDirective) _fgDirective: FormGroupDirective;`